# Linq Except Compare by certain field

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3

i have `List<Item> A` in my database and i got `List<Item> B` from outside. and I want to get the 
List A and B have the same properties.

```
List<Item> A

{ ID : 1, Name: "Tool A" , Status : 1, Price : 100 }
{ ID : 2, Name: "Tool B" , Status : 2, Price : 200 }
{ ID : 3, Name: "Tool C" , Status : 3, Price : 300 }
{ ID : 4, Name: "Tool D" , Status : 4, Price : 400 }
{ ID : 5, Name: "Tool E" , Status : 5, Price : 500 }

List<Item> B

{ ID : 1, Name: null , Status : 1, Price : 100 }
{ ID : 2, Name: null , Status : 2, Price : 200 }
{ ID : 3, Name: null , Status : 3000, Price : 300 }
{ ID : 4, Name: null , Status : 4, Price : 40000 }
{ ID : 5, Name: null , Status : 5, Price : 500 }
```

I want to store updated data into database which would be

```
{ ID : 3, Name: "Tool C", Status : 3000, Price : 300 }
{ ID : 4, Name: "Tool D", Status : 4, Price : 40000 }
```

the values of the property "Name" are from `List<Item> A` even though they are null in `List<Item> B`

I was thinking something like this but it gives me an odd results

```
var ChagnedList = A.AsEnumerable()
   .Where(aa => B.Any(bb => aa.Status != bb.Status || aa.Price != bb.Price))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExceptBy method in [MoreLinq](http://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/):

```
var ChagnedList = A.AsEnumerable()
                   .ExceptBy(B, item => new {item.Status,item.Price});
```